# Scalatest provide position different file for assertion

Tags: scala, scalatest

How do I provide a `Position` to `org.scalatest.Assertions.assert` so that it reports a different position rather that the default one?

My problem is that I have a parent test class and a child test class. The child test class uses an assertion method in parent. This causes the test fail messages to be pointed to the parent method instead of the child method.

For example, I have a parent test class as:

```scala
abstract class ParentSpec[A <: TestSubject] extends FunSuite {
  protected def checkId(underTest: => A, expectedId: Int): Assertion = {
    assert(underTest.id == expectedId)
  }
}
```

And a child test class as:

```scala
class FooSpec extends ParentSpec[Foo] {
  test("check id") {
    checkId(Foo(1, 2, 3), 999) // this fails
  }
}
```

If the test fails, then the assertion reports that the issue is from `ParentSpec.scala`. How can I change this to `FooSpec.scala`?

I noticed that `assert` takes in an implicit `Position`

```scala
def assert(condition: Boolean)(implicit prettifier: Prettifier, pos: source.Position): Assertion
```

can I somehow provide the position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the `checkId` method also accept an implicit position:

```
protected def checkId(underTest: => A, expectedId: Int)(implicit pos: Position): Assertion
```

That's it. Now the messages should point at invocations of `checkId` (unless it's called from yet another function with its own position parameter).

Now a few words about how this works:

It's all based on [where the compiler looks for implicits](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html). The implicit `Position` is needed for your `assert` call which is inside `checkId`. If `checkId` accepts an implicit `Position` parameter by itself, that parameter is simply passed forward to `assert`. But when this parameter is absent, the compiler will fall back to `Position.here` (defined in `Position` companion object). This thing is a macro which materializes the position at which it is called.

Comment: It works! Thanks. A minor issue though, my IDE (IntelliJ) is not providing a hyperlink to the file itself, even though the filename and line is shown correctly. Do you know any fix for that?

Comment: @krismath nope, sorry